# how does GitHub find terraform files after moving them to a folder, instead of root directory

Tags: github, terraform, yaml, github-actions

I have this GitHub repo:

```
_
 |_ .github/workflows/myworkflow.yaml
 |_ terraform/terraformInFolder.tf
 |_ terraformInRootDir.tf
```

my workflow runs terraform bash scripts like terraform apply, vaidate, etc...
it can only run the .tf files in the **root directory**. I couldn't find a way to run the files in the **folder**.
I tried to use `with: path:`  but `with` cannot be used with `run`.

Here is my workflow:

```
name: deployment-workflow

on: push
jobs:
  terraform_apply:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1


    - name: Verify Terraform version
      run: terraform --version

    - name: Terraform init
      env:
        AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
        AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
      run: terraform init -input=false

    - name: Terraform validation
      run: terraform validate

    - name: Terraform apply
      env:
        AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
        AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
      run: terraform apply -auto-approve -input=false
```

How can i include the path to my .tf files in the folder?

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the parameter

> -chdir=< folder location >

to redirect the execution of terraform. I update your code to this:

```
name: deployment-workflow

on: push
jobs:
  terraform_apply:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1


    - name: Verify Terraform version
      run: terraform --version

    - name: Terraform init
      env:
        AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
        AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
      run: terraform -chdir="./terraform" init -input=false

    - name: Terraform validation
      run: terraform -chdir="./terraform" validate -no-color

    - name: Terraform apply
      env:
        AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
        AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
      run: terraform -chdir="./terraform" apply -auto-approve -input=false
```

Answer (score 0):

Terraform doesn’t expect you to break up your modules using directories like this. All files in a module are loose in the top level of the module’s folder. In the `tree` you provided, your root module contains only a single file: `terraformInRootDir.tf`. The subdir is ignored.

If you want to add structure, you can do so by creating submodules. The files of a submodule are in a subdirectory, but you have to declare the submodule in code by specifying the path and passing the input variables.

You can learn more about how Hashicorp recommends you structure your repo [in the docs](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules/develop/structure).